# How do i convert from ASCII to Decimal

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
final byte[] bslval = data1.getByteArray(HRPService.BSL_VALUE);

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        if (bslval != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "BYTE BSL VAL =" + bslval[0]);
                //TextView bsltv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BodySensorLocation);
                EditText bsltv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditSensorLocation);
                String bslstr = new String(bslval, "UTF-8");
                bsltv.setText(bslstr);                                
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
```

The EditText does show the value as a "d" but not as "64" (which I want). How do I convert this to a decimal instead?

Comment: why would it do that ? `new String(byte[], String)` creates a new String using the bytes according to the encoding. TextUtils.join may do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String bslstr = String.valueOf(bslval[0] & 0xff);
```

This assumes, the value is actually in `bslval[0]`. The `& 0xff` is there to get positive results for byte values between `(byte)0x80` and `(byte)0xff`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simpler string concatenation if you only want to set the first byte value `bslval[0]` as text.

```
bsltv.setText(bslval[0] + "");
```